# Is it possible to queue up a content block within a plugin block?

Tags: blocks, plugins

I have a plugin block that returns a render array based on taxonomy of the node. I want to make a default custom block appear when there's no taxonomy term selected. I've tried this:

```
else {
  $block = Block::load('default_cta');
  $render = \Drupal::entityManager()->
  getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block);
  return $render;
}
```

Which is how I'd render a content block, but this throws `Call to undefined method Drupal\\block\\Entity\\Block::isDefaultRevision()`. This post [How can I programmatically display a block?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171686/how-can-i-display-block-programatically-in-drupal-8) describes the difference between a content block and plugin block, and I'm guessing I can't call one within the other. Is there another way to do this without creating the default render array from scratch?