# Custom blocks created as a plugin in a module not showing for Block::load()

Tags: 8

I have a couple of blocks that have been created using the `... extends BlockBase` syntax in my module. They work perfectly fine, and I can add them on the blocks layout page, can add them into DS as a field, etc. They definitely exist fine.

However, when I try and render them using `Block::load()`, they won't show up, unlike other blocks that work fine.

For example, if I have the following docblock:

```
/**
 * Provides a 'Cute Cats' Block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "cute_cats",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Cute cats yo"),
 * )
 */
 class CuteCats extends BlockBase { ... }
```

... and then try and call it like this:

```
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('cute_cats');
return render(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('block')
  ->view($block));
```

Any idea why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Block::load()` loads a configured block, that means a block that is placed in the block layout. It does not load plugins.

The name of the configured block is displayed in the block layout as *Machine name*.

You can place the block in the *Disabled* section, if you only want to configure the block, but don't want to show the block in a region.

Comment: Thanks, I found the code for plugin blocks and so have answered my own question. Appreciate the response though :)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was using the wrong syntax, and should have used a different one for plugin blocks (as @4x4 mentioned). The correct code for plugin blocks is:

```
$plugin_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');
$block = $plugin_manager->createInstance($block_id, array());
return render($block->build());
```

Comment: Got the info from http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/171733/14151, so thanks to @googletorp for that one

Comment: That's basically the same, you configure the block on the fly with an empty configuration. You simply skip the step to configure the block.