# Can't render a block due to recoverable fatal error

Tags: 8, blocks

I had code to programmatically render a block.

```
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('bartik_search');
$block_content = \Drupal::entityManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('block')
  ->view($block);
return array('#markup' => drupal_render($block_content));
```

After updating to Drupal 8.2.x, I get the following error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder::view() must implement interface

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Do you check block with delta **bartik_search** exited? You can debug with kint($block) to see it.

Comment: You should not need to call the view builder. Block plugins have a ::build method that returns a render array, which you can just return. What are you trying to do that you need to render and then place into a new render array?

Comment: Hi @Jonh , I check block **bartik_search** exited..

Comment: Hi @mradcliffe ..so what's solution ? Could you show code ?

Comment: I really do not understand what you are trying to do? Are you trying to place a Search Form or a Search Block Form on the page somewhere? Where on the page? Through what mechanism? Knowing that I can provide the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically display a block?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171686/how-can-i-programmatically-display-a-block)

Answer (score 2):

The error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to `Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder::view()` must implement interface `Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface`

usually is caused by viewing the invalid block (NULL). So for some reason `Block::load()` fails to load your block (`bartik_search`). So clear your caches and check whether the [block exists at *Block Layout* page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2394423), theme is enabled and permissions are configured properly. If this still happening and the block is definitely there, please [raise a relevant issue ticket](https://www.drupal.org/node/73179).

You can always add the condition or try/catch block whether the code loads the block correctly.

Please also note that <del>`drupal_render()`</del> is deprecated and you should return `$block_content` instead.<sup>[@googletorp](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171686/how-can-i-programmatically-display-a-block/171738#comment228649_171753)</sup> Or use `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot()` instead.

See also: [How can I programmatically display a block?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/171686/1908)