# Webform block not rendered context in d8

Tags: blocks, webforms

After execution the Webform "context" not rendering. It throws error like
`Message LogicException: Bubbling failed. in Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext()`.

I tried to render programmatically like this:

```
return \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($block_content);
```

Below is the code,

if ($node->field_type->value == 'block') {
   try {
     $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($node->field_structure->value);
                if ($block != null) {
                    $block_content = \Drupal::entityManager()
                    ->getViewBuilder('block')
                    ->view($block);
                    try {
                        if (!empty($_POST['form_token']) && $block->getPluginId() == 'webform_block') {
                            return \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($block_content);
                        } else {
                            return \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($block_content);
                        }
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        return '';
                    }
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return '';
            }
        }

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you show more of the example code of where you're trying to use this?

Comment: I suspect that this is not webform issue/question but a block related issue/question. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171686/how-can-i-programmatically-display-a-block

Comment: I updated my question