# D8: render block in node?

Tags: 8, nodes, blocks

We're migrating some code to D8 and in some of our nodes' body field we used to call PHP code directly with the now defunct `module_invoke` to render a block in the node before the content.

All the examples I can find explain how to do that in D8 with themes or templates, but I need to render the block inside the node body using PHP code, is there a way to do that?

We already tried:

```
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->invoke($module, $hook, $args = array())
```

but it doesn't show the block, presumably because it only takes modules?

From this [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/171733/56564) we also tried:

```
$block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load($bid); 
$render = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block);
```

Trying to print or render `$render` either doesn't show anything or literally prints out an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically display a block?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171686/how-can-i-programmatically-display-a-block)

Comment: Is it a block provided by a module or is it a custom content block? (Content block = You went to Structure > Block Layout > Custom block library > Add custom block). If it's a module block, use `block` view builder instead of `block_content`.

Comment: @Beebee just tried with block, same behaviour. Printing $render just prints an array, rendering it doesn't show anything :(

Comment: You shouldn't even need to render it. Where's the code placed?
 It should be in `THEME_preprocess_node`. Just add it to $variables as `$variables['mycustomblock'] = $render` and in node.twig.html print it out with `{{ mycustomblock }}`

Comment: @Beebee the code is directly in the node body, the thing is it's content specific so we can't put it in a template

Comment: That's a very important piece of information you haven't made clear in the original question. You're trying to put PHP code in the node's body value?

Comment: @Beebee yes I am, it says so at the top "...in some of our node body we used to call..."

Comment: Why not just add a "block_id" field to that node type? You're creating the blocks from the block interface anyway. I wouldn't really put PHP code anywhere near field values if I were you.

Comment: @Beebee I don't understand what you mean, we do have a block_id. Also sorry my original wording wasn't clear

Comment: So instead of putting PHP code that renders a certain block (the only variable part is `$bid` right?), add a field that stores the block ID and move the PHP code into a theme. I don't understand the reasoning behind wanting to put PHP code in a node body.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

In hook_preprocess_page() add the following code.

```
$block_entity = Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load(BLOCK_ID);// BLOCK_ID
$block_view = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block_entity, 'DISPLAY_VIEW_NAME');
if ($block_view) {
    $variables['page']['my_block'] = $block_view;
}
```

In your Twig template, print the block with the following code.

```
{% if page.my_block %}
  {{ page.my_block }}
{% endif %}
```