# Altering block to include another block

Tags: blocks

I am using the following code for a block.

```
  public function build() {
    $current_client = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('epensions');
    $build = [];
    $build['client'] = array(
      '#markup' => $current_client->get('scheme_name').' : '. $current_client->get('sponsor_name'),
    );

    $build['change_link'] = array(
      '#title' => $this->t('Change'),
      '#prefix' => '<br>',
      '#type' => 'link',
      '#url' => Url::fromRoute('epensions.sponsor.selector')
    );

    $build['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;

  return $build;

  }
```

I want the results to appear to the right of the account details in Bootstrap and show the same way "My account" & "Log Out" appears.

> [image: screenshot]

Kindly help.

Comment: See this on how to load a block programmatically. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171686/how-can-i-programmatically-display-a-block

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could approach this.  Rather than create a new block, one way would be to add the 'change_link' item to the User Account menu, and then use hook_link_alter to add the sponsor_name text in front of the new link.

Another way would be to use the Block Layout settings (admin/structure/block) to position your block in the desired region (wherever the account details are positioned) and give it the desired weight within that region.  Then use CSS to float it to the right of the account details.

If you really want to position block output within another block, you could use hook_block_view_alter.