# How to get the context node in a custom block inside a views list?

Tags: views, 8, blocks

I have a view which displays all pictures of the content type `photo`.
I've set some fields in this view for the display.

This is how iIrender the list of pictures:

**views-view-fields--photo.html**

```html
<figure class="element-item {{ fields['name'].content|lower }}">
    <a href="{{ fields['field_photo_1'].content|lower }}">
        <img src="{{ fields['field_photo'].content }}"/>
    </a>
    <figcaption>
        <div class="date">{{ fields['field_date'].content }}</div>
        <div class="lieu">{{ fields['field_lieu'].content }}</div>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
{{ drupal_block('comment_block') }}
```

I use the [Twig tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module to render a custom block in this template. This block should load all comments for the picture. For that, I need to pass the `nid` of the node to my block.

Here's the code of the block:

**CommentBlock.php**

```php
/**
 * Provides a 'CommentBlock' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *  id = "comment_block",
 *  admin_label = @Translation("Comment block"),
 *  context = {
 *    "node" = @ContextDefinition("entity:node", label = @Translation("Node"))
 *  }
 * )
 */
class CommentBlock extends BlockBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface definition.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  /**
   * Constructs a new CommentBlock object.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('entity_type.manager')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {

    $build = [];

    $node = $this->getContextValue('node');
    kint($node->id());

    $build['#theme'] = 'comment_ajax';

    return $build;
  }

}
```

What I try is to get the context of the views row into my block. But I get this error:

> ```
> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\ContextException : Required contexts without a value: node
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

I can load my block from `template_preprocess_views_view_fields()` to link with the `nid` but I try to understand the context annotation.

---

#### Update

Here's a picture of the view, my custom block returns just a link name "Comment".

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I now load the block programmatically instead of using `drupal_block` in the preprocess.

```
$block             = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('commentblock');
$variables['test'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('block')
  ->view($block);
```

Then I print this block in **views-view-fields.html.twig**:

```
{{ fields['title'].content }}
{{ test }}
```

If I `kint` the context in my block I still get an error except if I set the annotation `required = FALSE`.

```
 *   context = {
 *     "node" = @ContextDefinition(
 *       "entity:node",
 *       label = @Translation("Current Node"),
 *       required = FALSE,
 *     )
 *   }
```

But the context is still empty.

Comment: I'd really love to know how you managed it in the end and are looking forward to see a cool answer from you added below. You'll find a way. I'm sure!

Comment: as soon as i find a way i ll update this post, thanks :)

Comment: Just a note if you arrive here from Google: As of Drupal v9 you have to use the context_**definitions** annotation `context_definitions = {"node" = @ContextDefinition(...)}` instead of the old `context = {"node" = @ContextDefinition(...)}`

Answer (score 5):

You might have to un-require the context with `required = FALSE`:

```php
 *   context_definitions = {
 *     "node" = @ContextDefinition(
 *       "entity:node",
 *       label = @Translation("Current Node"),
 *       required = FALSE,
 *     )
 *   }
```

And when you place the block you have to choose from where the block will get the node value:

[image]

Comment: The block is placed programmatically, and i have like 50 picture render by the views module on one url

Comment: @Kevin – Answer updated.

Comment: @Kevin – But I'm afraid this only kills the error but still won't give you what you want. Have you already seen this [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/171733/15055)? Under "Plugin blocks" he seems to mention where you can hook in to add contexts.

Comment: @Kevin – And I guess `drupal_block()` inside Twig is too limited. I'd say preprocess function and pass a render array over to Twig instead.

Comment: so i have load the block in the preprocess, and pass it to the $variable for print the block in the template. i have the same problem. When i add required = FALSE in annotation, i have no error but the $this->getContextValue('node'); is empty

Comment: That's when [this other answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/171733/15055) kicks in. You have to pass the contexts when loading the block. He mentions something about contexts which is exactly what you need. You have to pass your node objects at this exact point.

Comment: I was initially confused why my block did not have a select field for the node context - it is required to set validation criteria on the view's contextual filter first for the field to appear.

Answer (score 3):

Block-plugins that inherit from `BlockBase` can have their context values directly set via [`ContextAwarePluginBase::setContextValue($key, $value)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Plugin%21ContextAwarePluginBase.php/function/ContextAwarePluginBase%3A%3AsetContextValue/8.7.x). This method can be used by a preprocess function to inject context that isn't otherwise available from the route or environment.

In my case I have a block that needs a `group` entity in its context:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\middlebury_course_hub\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

/**
 * Provides a block with a link to the section's roster.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "course_hub_roster_link",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Roster Link"),
 *   category = @Translation("Course Hub"),
 *   context = {
 *     "group" = @ContextDefinition(
 *       "entity:group",
 *       label = @Translation("Current Group"),
 *       required = FALSE
 *     )
 *   }
 * )
 */
class RosterLinkBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function blockAccess(AccountInterface $account) {
    /** @var \Drupal\group\Entity\GroupInterface $group */
    if (($group = $this->getContextValue('group')) && $group->id()) {
      if ($group->hasPermission('view group_membership content', $account)) {
        return AccessResult::allowed();
      }
    }
    return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    // This block varies per group.
    $build['#cache']['contexts'] = ['group'];
    $build['#theme'] = 'course_hub_roster_link';
    /** @var \Drupal\group\Entity\GroupInterface $group */
    if (($group = $this->getContextValue('group')) && $group->id()) {
      $build['#group'] = $group;
    }

    // If no group was found, cache the empty result on the route.
    return $build;
  }

}
```

I wanted to display this block for each group entity that was a row of a view result. By adding a preprocess function to my module I could inject the `group` context:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_hook().
 */
function middlebury_course_hub_preprocess_group(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'dashboard_item') {
    // Add the roster-link block to the build-array.
    $block = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')
               ->createInstance('course_hub_roster_link');
    $block->setContextValue('group', $variables['group']);
    if ($block->access(\Drupal::currentUser())) {
      $variables['content']['roster_link'] = $block->build();
      $variables['content']['roster_link']['#weight'] = 2;
    }
  }
}
```

This same technique should work for nodes as well using `$block->setContextValue('node', $node);` in your `hook_preprocess_node` function.

Answer (score 2):

So after many try, I haven't found a standalone solution for my block with the context plugin. But I found a way with a preprocess function.

Here's how I get the `nid` from my views row :

```
function comment_ajax_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables) {

  $block_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');
  $config        = ['nid' => $variables['row']->nid];
  $plugin_block  = $block_manager->createInstance('comment_block', $config);

  $variables['blockComment'] = $plugin_block->build();
}
```

In this preprocess function, I get the row `nid` and I use it in the block config.

And in my custom block:

```
public function build() {

  $build = [];

  $blockConfig     = $this->getConfiguration();
  $build['#theme'] = 'comment_ajax';
  $build['#nid']   = $blockConfig['nid'];

  return $build;
}
```

I get back the `nid` from the block configuration.

That works but I was looking for a way without preprocessing, just with the context.

I'm still looking for a better way :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I've visited /admin/structure/block remove the block and clear cache. After that I added block again and the context node becomes accessible