# Use a twig template instead of a render array in a custom module admin page

Tags: 8, theming

I have a Drupal 8 custom module, and I want to display its configuration page using the admin theme.

Usually, for this kind of pages I use, in the `_controller` property of my route, rather :

- a class that extends `\Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase` (for a simple form-like config page)
- a custom controller that extends `\Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase` and returns a [renderable array](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/render-arrays)

For this module, I need to use complex HTML structure and a Javascript library for its configuration page. Writing all this directly in a `#markup` property of a render array would be too much work and highly not-maintainable.

Is it possible to write a custom template (twig or not), to render it programmatically and insert the result into a [`container` element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Container.php/class/Container/8.5.x) or in a `#markup` property ?
And, as I use the Seven admin theme, I would like to do this without affecting the theme.

---

**[Resolved] Final solution :**

Combining leymannx answer and the elements mentioned below, I ended up with something that meet my requirements.

**mymodule.routing.xml**

```
mymodule.admin_ro:
  path: '/admin/config/mymodule/readonly'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\ReadOnlyController::index'
    _title: 'Module configuration - read only'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'view mymodule configuration'
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
    no_cache: TRUE
```

**ReadOnlyController.php**

```
class ReadOnlyController extends ControllerBase {

    public function index(){
        return array(
            '#type' => 'container',
            '#theme' => 'test-template',
            '#test_var' => [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] // I needed an array type variable
        );
    }

}
```

**mymodule.module**

```
// Implements hook_theme()
function mymodule_theme( $existing, $type, $theme, $path ){
    return [
        'test-template' => [
            'render element' => 'container', // To render a simple container element
            'template' => 'test', // My template file name
            'variables' => [
                'test_var' => [] // Default value for my variable
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

And finally, my test template : **templates/test.html.twig**

```
<p>Hello !</p>
<!-- Just to see the content of my variable, after enabling twig debug mode -->
{{ dump(test_var) }}
```

---

**Related doc or posts**

- [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.5.x)
- [Form and render elements | Drupal API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements)
- [Create custom twig templates for custom module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/create-custom-twig-templates-for-custom-module)
- [How can I programmatically display a block?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171686/how-can-i-programmatically-display-a-block)
- [StackOverflow - Drupal 8 custom block (module) create twig template file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643897/drupal-8-custom-block-module-create-twig-template-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The back-end theme automatically switches by path. So if your route's path begins with `/admin` it will show the page in the admin theme.

```
MYMODULE.MYPAGE:
  path: '/admin/config/MYPAGE'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\MYMODULE\Form\MYFORM'
    _title: 'MYTITLE'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

---

To render a form inside your own template you could simply register a new theme implementation inside `MYMODULE/MYMODULE.module`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

  return [
    'MYNAME' => [
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template'       => 'MYTEMPLATE',
    ],
  ];
}
```

And in the form you set this as the form's `#theme`.

```
$form['#theme'] = 'MYNAME';
```

And in the `MYMODULE/templates/MYTEMPLATE.html.tiwg` template you print it like so:

```
<div class="foo bar">
  {{ form }}
</div>
```

---

Any additional library also can simply be `#attached` directly to the form.

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'MYMODULE/MYLIBRARY';
```

---

#### Read More

[[drupal.org] Create custom twig templates for custom module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/create-custom-twig-templates-for-custom-module).

Comment: Do you know if this is adaptable to render something else than a form ?

Comment: Yupp, that's the way it goes via [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.2.x).