# Render custom block using block.html.twig template

Tags: 8, blocks

I'm attempting to render a custom content block programmatically (created through the Custom Block Library UI) and I would like the block to render using block.html.twig as it would if I were to place it in a theme region. I have the block placed in a disabled region and I can get the block body field to render programmatically, but it is not wrapped in the usual block template and does not include the block title. I'm using the code to render a "content block" from the accepted answer here: [How can I programmatically display a block?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171686/how-can-i-programmatically-display-a-block)

```
$bid = ??? // Get the block id through config, SQL or some other means
$block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load($bid);
$render = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->
getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block);
return $render;
```

As I understand it, I need to render the instance of the custom block that I have placed inside the disabled region, so I would expect that I have to use the machine name of that instance. I've done a lot of searching and come up with nothing. It's strange that nobody else seems to want to render the block with the title in the block.html.twig template.

Comment: What template would the block right now be rendered with?

Comment: It renders using field--text-with-summary.html.twig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I was hoping for an answer that didn't involve installing a module because this seems like a simple task, but after some point you just have to give in. The [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module can do what I'm asking very easily. After installing, in a template where you want to render the block, add this:

`{{ drupal_entity('block', 'BLOCK_CONFIG_MACHINE_NAME') }}`

where BLOCK_CONFIG_MACHINE_NAME is the machine name of the block you have configured at /admin/structure/block/

This will render the block using `block.html.twig` and will render the title you have configured.

Documentation: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/rendering-blocks-with-twig-tweak

Comment: Twig Tweak probably isn't the worst. Can even imagine it in core some day.

Comment: I ended up running into this issue again and found my own thread here. I also found that there is actually an open core issue about this on Drupal.org:

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2704331

Comment: I would consider making twig_tweak a standard tool in you site configuration. My opinion is that twig_tweak is one of the most useful contrib modules available for Drupal 8.

Comment: I agree with you both that Twig Tweak is great. However I'm doubtful it will ever become part of core. Drupal 9 is deprecating functions that are wrappers around object oriented code. It seems to me that because a contrib module like Twig Tweak introduces wrapper functions which make our lives easier, it will never become part of core. I'm all for object oriented, but we shouldn't need to write 5+ lines of code to render a block with the proper template unless we choose to do it that way. Oh well.

Answer (score 8):

BlockContent is the only entity in Drupal not having a template of its own. So you have to wrap it in a template yourself:

```
$block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load($bid);
if ($block) {
  $content = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block);
  $build = [
    '#theme' => 'block',
    '#attributes' => [],
    '#configuration' => ['label' => 'My Block', 'label_display' => 'visible'],
    '#base_plugin_id' => 'block_content',
    '#plugin_id' => 'block_content:' . $block->uuid(),
    '#derivative_plugin_id' => $block->uuid(),
    '#id' => $block->id(),
    'content' => $content,
  ];
  return $build;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This does render the block in the block.html.twig template. It doesn't however use the block title/label configured in the instance of the block I placed in the disabled region. I'm certain there must be a way to do this because it seems like a simple task. Somehow Drupal core is doing the same thing when it renders a custom block inside of a region.

Comment: Since you've asked a code only question I've responded with the code you need to fulfill the task "render a custom block using block html twig template". When Drupal renders a block you've placed in the block layout it does the same, Twig Tweak probably as well. This is the basic usage of twig templates, they are invoked by building a render array with #theme. And when you want a block template you have to use `'#theme' => 'block'`, directly in your own code or via other code you've found in contrib. You can fill #configuration with the settings of a configured block if you want.

Comment: Thank you for the response! That's fair, I didn't mention the desire to render the configured title in the question title so as not to make too lengthy.

Comment: Yes, and your assumption "As I understand it, I need to render the instance of the custom block that I have placed inside the disabled region", is not the case, you don't need to do this only to store the label to retrieve it later to put it in the block template. A configured block is mainly used to place a block in a theme and region.