# Is a block render array built with EntityViewBuilderInterface::view supposed to render full block template or only inner fields?

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

After rendering custom blocks in templates, I got this js error:  *Quick Edit could not associate the rendered entity field markup*. What I've done so far :

In order to render repeatedly custom blocks in templates, I wrote this function in `mytheme.theme` :

```
function render_block_in_template($block_id) {
  // $block = Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('block_content')->load($block_id);
  $block = Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load($block_id);

  if(!empty($block)) {
    $block_content = Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getViewBuilder('block_content')
      ->view($block);

    if($block_content) {
      // kint($block_content);
      return $block_content;
    }
  }
}
```

And I call it in `mytheme_preprocess_node` :

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];

  if($node->bundle() == 'some_bundle') {
    $variables['some_block'] = render_block_in_template(12);
    $variables['some_other_block'] = render_block_in_template(13);
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then I render the blocks in `node--some-bundle.html.twig` :

```
{{ some_block }}
{{ some_other_block }}
```

**So far so good. But I got this js error from quickedit.js :**

> **Error**: Quick Edit could not associate the rendered entity field markup
> (with `[data-quickedit-field-id="block_content/12/body/fr/full"]`) with
> the corresponding rendered entity markup: no parent DOM node found
> with `[data-quickedit-entity-id="block_content/12"]`. This is typically
> caused by the theme's template for this entity type forgetting to
> print the attributes.

Which brought me to this issue : [Custom blocks break layout builder module - Quick Edit could not associate the rendered entity field markup](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3072231), but applying the patch did not change anything, and further reading let me thing this is not exactly related.

If I `{{ kint(some_block) }}` in twig, the #attributes key with expected values is here :

[image]

and this is the HTML output :

```
<div data-quickedit-field-id="block_content/12/body/fr/full" class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item">
    
// FIELD CONTENT

</div>
```

Last, manually wrapping it with the following removes the error :

```
<div data-quickedit-entity-id="block_content/12">

</div>
```

So it appears that the above *wrapper part* of block template is not rendered, only the fields are and it causes the error.

Is there indeed a bug or am I doing things wrong ?

Comment: The block content entity is the only entity in Drupal which doesn't have its own template. Instead it should be rendered inside of a general block template, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267150/render-custom-block-using-block-html-twig-template

Comment: take a look at this issue https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2978799

Comment: @berramou thanks, I knew this issue, I don't think it applies unfortunately  :(

Comment: I think the new template node--some-bundle.html.twig what cause the issue, I just tested another suggestion template like node--article.html.twg without any custom variables  and I get the same error, first of all try to render your variables in the original template node.html.twig to see if the error comes from twig template or the preprocess

Comment: @4k4, great this solves the  issue. It also leaded to a bunch of new notices all beginning with **Undefined index: provider in...** . My 2 cents : `'#attributes' => ["data-quickedit-entity-id"=>"block_content/".$block->id()],
        '#configuration' => ['label' => '', 'label_display' => 'invisible', 'provider' => ''],`