# How to print Blocks in commerce-product.html.twig?

Tags: 8, commerce

I am looking at building a Drupal 8 Commerce 2 product display through twig but I am having issues with how to print custom blocks in this template file. (And also testing these in normal `page.html.twig` as well)

Looking at the Custom Block Library (`/admin/structure/block/block-content`) I can see that the ID is '4', as the ID from the Edit URL is 4. (`http://www.example.com/block/4`)

I have installed the module Twig Tweak and tried all the combinations below in the commerce-product.html.twig, and each time I get a WSOD

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

`{{ drupal_entity('block_content', 4) }}`

`{{ drupal_entity('block_content', '4') }}`

`{{ drupal_block('block_content:4') }}`

`{{ drupal_entity('block', 4) }}`

`{{ drupal_entity('block', '4') }}`

I have also tried in my example.theme file:

```
function theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('4');
  $block_content = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getViewBuilder('block')
    ->view($block);
 $variables['productinfo'] = $block_content;
}
```

Then in *.html.twig with lots of cache flushing before and after:

`{{ productinfo }}`

I also seam to be not even able to use any of the examples from the Twig Tweak Cheat Sheet, as each one of these I add to my any `*.html.twig` I get the WSOD.

`{{ drupal_view('who_s_new', 'block_1') }}`

or

`{{ drupal_region('sidebar_first') }}`

How do I print custom blocks into a `commerce-product.html.twig` template?

Comment: What's the error message? It'll be in your server logs and/or the watchdog

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_preprocess_commerce_product` to load the block and pass the variable to your twig file.

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_commerce_product(array &$variables) {
  $block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load(4);
  $variables['custom_block'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->
    getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block);
}
```

and then in your twig file you will have the `{{ custom_block }}` variable set.

On a sidenote, [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/171733/90423) helps a lot when trying to programatically load blocks.